# Kafka Source JDBC Connector with query on incrementing column is not showing any results recently although it used to work before

Tags: apache-kafka

So first of all I want to say that this connector configuration was working fine for a few months. Recently however there was a DB switchover and it stopped working(I have another identical connector on the same source but without query mode and that one is working fine after DB switchover) . The connector status is showing running and there are no helpful logs in the worker log. Everything is apparently working as intended according to Kafka.(including committed offsets)

This particular connector config had a query like follows at the very beginning

***SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ID WHERE ID>50000)***

Now let's assume 50000 records have been added since I started the connector at the very beginning and then it broke after the DB Switchover. Now the last added record is of ID 100000. Since then 1000+ records have not been added from the DB.

Here were 2 of my attempted workarounds.

1. I updated & restarted the connector with query ***SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ID WHERE ID>100000)***
   This however resulted the same situation as before. Kafka commits offsets as per usual.
2. I deleted the previous connector, created a new connector on a new name with the same updated query ***SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ID WHERE ID>100000)***
   This is also unfortunately the same situation again. Offsets committed as per usual.

Has anyone encountered such a situation?
I'm on Kafka 2.2

Comment: Update: I fixed the problem by changing the connect-config/connect-offset topics and running over a different Connect Worker. However I can't really call it an acceptable fix.